# owl-carousel implementation problem in nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a problem implementing v-owl-carousel with nuxtjs.

When I try:

```
import carousel from 'v-owl-carousel'
```

An error message appears

> document is undefined

I followed the configuration recommendations as requested on this page https://github.com/93gaurav93/v-owl-carousel but nothing works ...

someone can help me ? can someone give me a track?

config empty project

```
{
  "name": "nuxtjs_test_owl_carousel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My gnarly Nuxt.js project",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.0",
    "v-owl-carousel": "^1.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried in an empty project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/

> This is due to the server-side rendering. If you need to specify that
>   you want to import a resource only on the client-side, you need to use
>   the process.client variable.
>
> For example, in your .vue file:
>
> if (process.client) {   require('external_library') }

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, it's works, i took some time to do further test

Answer (score 0):

Owl carousel doesn't support SSR (server side rendering), you must use  as given in below example:

```
<no-ssr> <!-- important to add no-ssr-->
  <carousel :options>
    ...content
  </carousel>
</no-ssr>
```